# How to remove a number in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

First declaration a arr:

```
 int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Second:

```
 arr1[3] = default(int);
```

do this aim for remove a num in this arr.
but i can find this number using index 3,why?
Since I've already deleted this element, why can I still access this element while traversing the group?

Comment: With `arr1[3]=default(int);` you *assign default value* of `int` (`0`) to the forth array's item. If you want to remove item, *change* array `int[]` to `List<int>` and call `RemoveAt(3)`

Comment: Do you want to delete/remove the last item or any arbitrary item?

Comment: default(int) is a ZERO. not a deletion

Comment: Arrays are of fixed size and do not allow easy insertion and removal of elements. You can of course laboriously do this "by hand" in shifting all the elements following the element to be removed one position to the left and then resize the array to shrink it by one. But why would you do that when there is List<T> available that supports dynamic insertion/addition and removal of elements...

Comment: You can't change the size of an array. (For the pedants: yes, there are resize methods, but they create new arrays and copy the data). If you want to remove items, you should use a `List<int>`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar "_but they create new arrays and copy the data_" That applies to List<T> as well.

Comment: Using C++ to delete a specified element in an array, the deleted element cannot be accessed using the index.

Comment: What does C++ have to do with this?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Where did I suggest that it didn't apply to `List<int>` too? I was simply stating that it doesn't _resize_ the existing array, pre-empting someone saying "aha! but DiplomacyNotWar, `Array.Resize` exists!".

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - very oversimplification and will most likely cause  confusion, as someone who is only consuming the api your comment feels wrong, even if under the hood that my be correct

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, your comment strongly implies that. You explicitly pointed out the fact of creating/copying arrays is a cost of resizing arrays while then List<T> suggesting as an alternative. Please don't get smart with me.

Comment: @MySkull It doesn't. I explicitly led with "for the pedants". Don't make silly comments, and I won't have to get smart with you.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, it does. No silly comment...

Comment: @MySkull how so? That's your interpretation. I know my intent writing my own comment for god sake.

Comment: I'm sorry I won't @your reply. Although I've seen some talk about using List to remove elements, I don't know which method to use to remove elements from a new array. Using C++, we erase the specified element, thereby deleting the specified element, and an Exception occurs when we revisit the deleted index.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar "How so?" I just told you how two comments prior. I see you are still trying to get smart with me...

Comment: @MySkull I wasn't pointing it out as a cost. That's your mistake. I was pointing out that you're not actually resizing the array. In what way am I trying to get smart with you? I'm merely stating that you've misinterpreted what I meant by my comment.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - sorry, if I answer your question with a counter question, look at the given answer - does OP need to care if List<T> create a new instance of an array under the hood? the OP (a consumer of the API) doesn't have to deal with the a new instance, for the consumer it doesn't "feel" like a new instance. what ever the list may do under the hood isn't of interest of the consumer of an api

Comment: I'm sorry I won't @ your reply. Thank you all so much for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can remove item at index `index` by shift and [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-6.0):

```
      int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

      int index = 3;

      // Let it be a good old for loop; alternative is
      // Array.Copy(arr1, index + 1, arr1, index, arr1.Length - index - 1);
      for (int i = index; i < arr1.Length - 1; ++i)
        arr1[i] = arr1[i + 1];

      Array.Resize(ref arr1, arr1.Length - 1);
```

However, you can switch from array `int[]` to `List<int>` and call [RemoveAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=net-6.0):

```
      var arr1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

      int index = 3;

      arr1.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: For GC in .NET can not deal garbage in array?Should I must resize this array to newArray or switch from array to List?No method delete it by array self?

Comment: @JiaChengZ As I said in the comments, you can't resize an array. Rephrased: you can't change the length of an array. How can you remove an item if you can't change the length of an array? `Array.Resize` is a convenience method to save you creating a new (shorter) array and copying the data you want to save manually.

Comment: Restricted Thank you very much for your reply. So can I think that C# cannot change the length of the array itself so that it cannot delete elements from itself, while C++ can change the length of the array so that it can delete the specified element on the basis of its own array.

Comment: @JiaChengZ: let .net do resizing for you (in the most optimal way), that's why switch to `List<int>`

Comment: The reason why I ask this question is that after converting to List, it will take up extra space for a program, so that a program may have a larger space complexity. So, is there such a possibility?

Comment: `you can switch to List<>` - technically you *can* do many things. However, if you need dynamic adding and deleting in the middle, you should use data structure, that does not have `O(n)` time for this. Otherwise you can easily end up with software, that is thousand times slower than user can accept. `List<>` is not good structure for this.